# import data from OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet

Tags: neo4j

I'm using OpenOffice Calc and NEO4J and I'm trying to import data from spreadsheet.

I have this structure:
[image]

I've already read [this](https://neo4j.com/blog/importing-data-into-neo4j-the-spreadsheet-way/), and when I write `"create n:"&A2&"{id:"&A2&",name:"'&B2&"'};"` nothing happens.

I expect to read this: `(n1:{id:1, name:'Maria'}),`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So the formula `"create n:"&A2&"{id:"&A2&",name:"'&B2&"'};` when evaluated against the spreadsheet data sheet, will evaluate to (if it even evals):

```
create n:1{id:1,name:Maria'};
```

Which isn't valid due to the mismatching quotes, missing parenthesis and doesn't quite match what you expect, try this instead

```
="CREATE (n" & A2 & " {id:" & A2 & ", name:" & """" & B2 & """" & "});"
```

Which for me in a google sheet, evals to:

```
CREATE (n1 {id:1, name:"Maria"});
```